# Joomla insert subdomain into URL

Tags: php, joomla

For the sake of Load Sharing a subdomain URL should be used for images of a component. Is there a way to use Joomla Framework commands to generate a URL containig a subdomain.

```
// main domain
$uri = JUri::getInstance();
echo $uri->toString();  // https://www.example.com

// how to get this out of it?
echo $uri->toString();  // https://img.example.com
```

I've tried to create if with $uri->getScheme() and  $uri->getHost() commands but that seam too risky, because it should also work if the main domain is something like https://temp.example.com

Comment: Sounds like you don't really have clear and specific rules as to how that hostname should actually get extracted. As long as that is the case there is no way to give a clear answer. So the general reply can only be: use a regular expression.

Comment: The question is quite simple. For the sake of Load Sharing a subdomain URL should be used for images of a component.

Comment: May I ask this: what if your "main domain" is `internal.cms.example.org` and the image service is at `img.example.org`?

Comment: The Second-Level-Domain should be prefixed with the Subdomain (Third-Level) and it should be fine.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no clear definition of a "second level domain". There are fist level domains like `.co.uk`, so `example.co.uk` would be a second level domain. Don't get me wrong, I am not trying to be a pain in the ass. I am just trying to point out that your question for a generic solution is impossible to answer as long as you don't have clear rules. And terms like "second level domain" are vague. If this is just about "the stuff before the second last dot in the host name", then what I wrote in my first comment applies: use a regular expression.

Comment: Its a pretty transparent question in my eyes. Of course i could use regex, but the question was if the Joomla Framework has any tools for this. You can also do things like setHost() and so on.